# Upload to SharePoint with WebDav through proxy fails with HTTP 405

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, proxy, webdav

I am trying to upload a file into a SharePoint library by using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [WebDav .NET](http://www.independentsoft.de/webdav/tutorial/index.html) library from independentsoft. First I had the problem that the Upload-method returned an exception with HTTP 403. Than I realized that I have to go through a proxy. Now it's returning me HTTP 405. I also used the ClientOM but wasn't able to configure the proxy settings there so I still get a HTTP 403 there.

The code i am using for WebClient and WebDav .NET is the following:

**WebClient:**

```
webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
string[] bypassList = { "localhost" };
webClient.Proxy = new WebProxy("proxy", true, bypassList, new NetworkCredential("user", "password"));
try
{
    byte[] response = webClient.UploadFile("http://sharepoint/testBlankSite/testLibrary/TestUpload.txt", "PUT", @"...\Desktop\TestUpload.txt");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

**WebDav .NET**

```
NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
string[] bypassList = { "localhost" };
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("proxy", true, bypassList, new NetworkCredential("user", "password"));
WebdavSession session = new WebdavSession(credential, proxy);

Resource resource = new Resource(session);
try
{
    resource.Upload("http://sharepoint/testBlankSite/testLibrary/TestUpload.txt", @"...\Desktop\TestUpload.txt");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

Has anyone an idea why this isn't working and how I can solve this?

Comment: Have you looked at a fiddler trace to see what HTTP method the WebDav code is using under the hood?
Also FYI, CSOM will just use the proxy settings according to the preferences of the current user, I'd suggest that you should be going the CSOM route.

Comment: Just to add to Gavin's comments, I would highly recommend using CSOM or REST APIs to upload documents rather than WebDAV. was there any particular reason you were using this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common problem with SharePoint. Check out these links:

[SharePoint, WebDAV, and a Case of the 405 Status Codes](http://sharepointinterface.com/2009/12/28/sharepoint-webdav-and-a-case-of-the-405-status-codes/)

[SharePoint 2013 - Disable WebDAV use on SharePoint](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2758444)

As @GavinB and @Jeremy mentioned, the alternative is the client-side object model, i.e. [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.aspx). This library is just a wrapper and it performs HTTP requests that are similar to the ones you are trying.